# Can Console2 be used with Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, console2

I'm a big Console2 fan, and I've recently been introduced to the power of PowerShell. Is it possible to have the latter (aka the PowerShell interpretive shell) inside the former?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Console2 settings, set the shell to:

`%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Because for something this simple a blog post is not an answer.

Answer (score 21):

Yeah, that is what I use. ( Update - Nowadays, I use [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/))

Refer to this excellent post from Scott Hanselman - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx

Comment: I use PowerShell in Console2 as well. Without any problem.

Comment: Be sure to read the comments regarding PowerShell - if you want PS to display colors, DO NOT set a custom text-color in Console2.

Comment: ConEmu is very good. See also very useful Aaron T Grogg's post comparing today's console alternatives: [Comparing PowerCmd vs. Console2 vs. ConsoleZ vs. ConEmu Vs. Cmder](https://aarontgrogg.com/blog/2015/07/31/a-better-windows-command-line-experience-comparing-powercmd-vs-console2-vs-consolez-vs-conemu-vs-cmder/)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you want an even better user experience while working with Console2+PowerShell duo, you can create a link to the Console2 executable, putting the following into the 'Shortcut'>'Target' field:

```
"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start c:\dir-with-console2\Console.exe"
```

Also, set the 'Run' option to 'Minimized' on the same tab.

Now when you add the directory containing this link to the PATH environment variable ('System Properties'>'Advanced') you'll get yourself a pretty nice "feature", namely no matter where you'll run this link from, it will always set your working directory for Powershell to the "current one" (the one you have run the link from - similarly to how cmd behaves).